# Get a separate bar for each row in Plotly when data has duplicate categories

Tags: pandas, visualization, plotly-python, plotly-express

I have a very simple dataframe with some duplicated category values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['Alpha', 'Beta','Beta','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Delta'], 'y': [12,11,9,7,5,3,1]})
```

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alpha | 12 |
| 1 | Beta | 11 |
| 2 | Beta | 9 |
| 3 | Beta | 7 |
| 4 | Gamma | 5 |
| 5 | Delta | 3 |
| 6 | Delta | 1 |

and I would like to use Plotly (Python) to produce a bar chart like I would get in Excel where each row has its own, separate bar like this:

[screenshot of example bar chart in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZayw.png)

Plotly produces something like this where the Beta and Delta values are sort of stacked on to each other:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(df, x='x', y='y')
```

[screenshot of same bar chart in plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R95we.png)

This feels like it should be easy to do but reading the Plotly docs / Google / SO searches so far have not produced a result (possibly because I struggled to work out the best search terms) but how to achieve this?

I have tried setting `type='category'` and `barmode='group'` and `categoryorder='total descending'` in various combinations, none of which have forced an individual, separate bar per row like in Excel that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not intuitive and had to dig beyond the px.bar docs for sure.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['Alpha', 'Beta','Beta','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Delta'], 'y': [12,11,9,7,5,3,1]})

fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y='y')
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df.index,
        ticktext = df.x
    )
)
fig.show()
```

gives

[image]